# UIBezierPath - Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2, uibezierpath

The following code creates the effect below:

```
  let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: headerRect.width, y: 0))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: headerRect.width, y: headerRect.height))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: headerRect.height-headerCutAway))
    headerMaskLayer?.path = path.CGPath
```

[image: Effect on Image]

I would like to change it so that the triangle is on the right rather on the left, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just swap the `y` value for the last two coordinates:

```
path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: headerRect.width, y: 0))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: headerRect.width, y: headerRect.height-headerCutAway))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: headerRect.height))
headerMaskLayer?.path = path.CGPath
```